# Wrong font type in pdf document

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I want to use [DMSans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/DM+Sans) for my document:

```
% !TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass{scrartcl} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DMSans}[Extension=.ttf,
UprightFont=*-Regular,
BoldFont=*-Bold,
ItalicFont=*-Italic,
BoldItalicFont=*-BoldItalic]
\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

The font files `DMSans-Bold.ttf`, `DMSans-BoldItalic.ttf`, `DMSans-Italic.ttf`, `DMSans-Medium.ttf`, `DMSans-MediumItalic.ttf`, `DMSans-Regular.ttf` are located in the same folder as the .tex file.
When opening the pdf with PDF-XChange editor it turns out that the font is LMsans, not DMSans as specified:
[image: wrong font]

Comment: you reset the default font to lm sans with `\renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}`

Comment: That declaration would make sense if you use `\setsansfont` instead of `\setmainfont`, but just removing it will do what you want.